# Connecting Firebase in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase

I have a Rails app from which I want to connect to Firebase and communicate with Rails. Basically I'll have the Rails app monitor Firebase for any changes and dynamically CRUD those changes in my views. I did a fair bit of searching but there's seems to be a lack of community resources on how to achieve this. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: are you talking about the real time database of firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use firebase-rails gem, it's description reads as follows:

> Ruby wrapper for the Firebase REST API.
>
> Changes are sent to all subscribed clients automatically, so you can update your clients in realtime from the backend.